# one sided touch sensor?

Tags: arduino

I am trying to create a glove that translates sign language into text. To do this i need touch sensors placed on the glove, however the only sensors that i can find detect a change in electromagnetic fields on both sides, meaning that if i place them on the glove they will be detecting a signal no matter what.

I have tried using multiple layers of thick electrical tape with no outcome.

when you touch the sensor it should recognise the press, however when on the glove it detects a press no matter what.

I am trying to observe the different letters signed. using flex sensors on each finger (already working fine) and touch sensors to further determine the position of the users finger. the error that i am having is putting the sensors on a glove so they do not activate when not pressed.

Comment: I thought I understood what you wanted from your first sentence. But then you describe it more and it's not clear to me how you want it to work. Draw some rough sketches and diagrams and scan them in. You can add them in using the "edit" button. Have you considered resistive bend sensors along the glove fingers?

Comment: This is beyond cool, if you can achieve it. I can't imagine how, though. Often, place near your body indicates certain subjects or ideas and those are established as part of the sign communication process and returned to during a conversation, repeatedly. I have no idea how you will write software smart enough to handle the very broad range of ASL in practice. I've learned it because my daughter is autistic and cannot tolerate sounds well. But it's a very complex and sophisticated language, as practiced. (It is a blessing to me at times -- in large crowded rooms where you don't need to shout.)

Comment: Check internet for Acceleglove using MEMS sensors. I recall the product has been discontinued, but i might be wrong.

Comment: what events are you trying to observe?

Comment: see edited version for more detail.

Comment: Why do you need touch sensors, rather than motion sensors?

Comment: Actually, I think you need **flex sensors**.

Comment: Can you please describe in detail how the touch sensors are supposed to get what you need? Most of us don't speak sign language and it's not clear to us why you need touch sensors. It seems that to a bunch of us, we're not sure why you need touch sensors to begin with. Like...are you just trying to figure out where different parts of the hand are touching itself to get more accurate gesture when combined with finger flex data from resistive bend sensors?

Comment: For example, an A-OK sign will register with thumb and index tip touching? Or a fist registers all 4 finger tips touching the palm with the thumb touching the 2nd joint of the index, middle, and ring finger? Or a "karate chop" registers as the inside edges of all fingers touching the inside edge of adjacent fingers? Or a peace V-victor sign registers the tip-side of the thumb's length touching the second joints of the pinky and ring finger? Or a middle finger registers the same as a fist except the middle finger is touching nothing?

Comment: Because if so, I would not actually use "touch" sensor as much as just a bunch of conductive contact points everywhere on the glove that run to a multiplexer that does something like a resistance or continuity test between every possible combination of expected contact. About 57 contacts. One for the palm and 4 per finger segment (one for each side). 3192 possible combos for a single hand touching itself, but some are impossible and others probably aren't used in gestures  so you can just not check those.  Then there's the one hand touching the other hand too. I hope you like lookup tables.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the interest. I am doing this project as a class assignment (year 10) and have only been given touch and flex sensors to work with. And yes the touch sensors are being used to combine the data with flex sensors to get a more accurate reading. All we are trying to do with the glove is determine numbers and the basic alphabet (A-Z).